# How can I remove "unnecessary" positions in a list in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this list: `df_list<-list(list(list(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)))`

There is multiples positions that I don "use". How can I remove this to have something like: `list(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)` ?

I am trying to find a function in `tidyverse` that makes this, but I can't find. I think it is from `purrr` package.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(purrr)

df_list <- list(list(list(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)))

flatten_dfr(df_list, .id = "id") %>% 
  group_split(id) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% select(-id))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)

pluck(df_list, 1, 1)
```

Or in base R you could simply do:

```
df_list[[1]][[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE` :

```
df_list %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

Or in `purrr` use `flatten` :

```
library(purrr)
df_list %>% flatten() %>% flatten()
```